# Laravel: Get all contestants of audition along with their votes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have Laravel Eloquent model with table structure

```
-contestants
  --id
-auditions
  --id
-audition_contestant
  --audition_id
  --contestant_id
-audition_votings
  --audition_id
  --contestant_id
  --vote
```

Contestant belongs to Many Auditions 
and Audition can have Many Contestants.

Whenever certain contestant of certain audition is voted, audition_votings table is used to store it.

I need to get all contestants of certain audition along with total vote that is being calculated
from audition_votings table.
for example endpoints will be

```
/audition/{id}/contestants
```

I have tried relation on Audition model like this

```php
    public function contestantVotes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contestant','audition_votings','audition_id','contestant_id')
            ->selectRaw('contestants.*,sum(vote) as vote')
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->groupBy('contestant_id')
            ->orderByDesc('vote');
    }
```

But this code will only show contestants if contestants is present on audition_votings but what i want is contestants on audition_contestant along with their total votes.

Raw sql query will also work.

Comment: Some sample data would help any reader of this question understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Also include the expected output.

Comment: Couldn't you just put `votes` as a column on `audition_contestant`? This looks like you're duplicating data, and having a separate table simple for the votes seems like a bad approach.